# Mouse Delay on Sony Desktop Running Windows 8

Tags: wireless-mouse

I have a Sony Desktop running windows 8. Mouse lags. It does not show up as a device in control panel.
I tried trouble shooter and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

If the mouse is working at all, then the problem is not with the mouse (or it needs new batteries). More likely there is some process running on your PC that is causing the lag.

Try scanning your computer with [MalwareBytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org).

If it's a Sony mouse, try finding the driver software here:

http://esupport.sony.com/US/p/select-system.pl?DIRECTOR=DRIVER